# Running Pig on Tez on Amazon EMR-4

Tags: apache-pig, amazon-emr, apache-tez

I'm trying to run pig on tez on amazon emr 4.5.0. The configuration works without tez, I'm just trying to get it to work on Tez.

To create the cluster (from the command line), we're using (TEZ_VERSION is defined as 0.5.2):

```
--bootstrap-actions Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/tez/bigtop/install-tez.rb,Args=[-v,$TEZ_VERSION,--tez-site,tez.lib.uris=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/tez/$TEZ_VERSION/tez-$TEZ_VERSION-minimal.tar.gz]
```

Additionally, I'm overwriting the PIG_CLASSPATH:

```
--configurations file://pig_tez_classification.json
```

Containing:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "hadoop-env",
    "Properties": {

    },
    "Configurations": [
      {
        "Classification": "export",
        "Properties": {
          "PIG_CLASSPATH": "/etc/tez/conf"
        },
        "Configurations": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The PIG_CLASSPATH is needed to prevent this error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJob  - Cannot submit DAG
org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezUncheckedException: Invalid configuration of tez jars, tez.lib.uris is not defined in the configuration
```

The tez.lib.uris overwrite is needed to prevent this error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJob (PigTezLauncher-0): Cannot submit DAG
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://ip-172-31-3-207.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020/apps/tez/0.5.2/tez-0.5.2-minimal.tar.gz
```

It appears the install script writes the tar.gz file to the right location in the hdfs, but when I log in over ssh afterwards, the file is not there. I think in EMR-4 the bootstrap actions are run at a different time, so before hdfs is available?

After all that, I still get this error:

```
WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJob  - Exception while gathering stats
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.tez.TezDAGStats.accumulateStats(TezDAGStats.java:191)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.tez.TezPigScriptStats.accumulateStats(TezPigScriptStats.java:180)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJob.run(TezJob.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezLauncher$1.run(TezLauncher.java:167)
```

Trying with tez version 0.8.2 yields:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJob  - Cannot submit DAG
org.apache.tez.dag.api.SessionNotRunning: TezSession has already shutdown
```

Which seems to be due to a difference in used tez version, because it still prints out:

```
INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.tez.TezPigScriptStats  - Script Statistics:

       HadoopVersion: 2.7.2-amzn-0                                                                                        
          PigVersion: 0.14.0-amzn-0                                                                                       
          TezVersion: 0.5.2                                                                                               
              UserId: hadoop
```

So does anyone know how to get pig on tez on amazon emr (whatever versions) running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm successfully running it with emr-4.4.0.  However, I was unable to get pig to work correctly with the tar.gz uploaded to HDFS.  Instead, I had to unpack the tarball and upload all the individual files, then set tez.lib.uris to hdfs:///apps/tez-0.8.2,hdfs:///apps/tez-0.8.2/lib

Comment: It looks like the install-tez.rb script provided by amazon (s3://support.elasticmapreduce/tez/bigtop/install-tez.rb) also unpacks the tarball, but then only uploads the tar.gz to hdfs (looking at the install_tez function). I'll try your versions and approach.